# Flask: Multiple dropdown selections

Tags: javascript

```
<select class="form-control" id="rating" name="rating">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="3" selected>3</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

I have a dropdown menu that I'm using to make a form using Flask.
Is there anyway to allow the user to keep selecting dropdown options?
Meaning to say, each time the user chooses an option another dropdown menu is rendered below and the previous one will display an [x] to delete that selection.

So, if the user wants to select multiple options they can do so, and I can have the flask app output these selections as a list

Comment: yes, it can be done in javascript, but where is your attemp?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I after re-reading your question I realized I didn't understand it right.  To create new select boxes dynamically you'll have to write some Javascript and doesn't really involve Flask. It looks like you're using Bootstrap, there might be a plugin to do what you want. However, as written, i think your question is a bit too broad